# Can an intent from MainActivity be used in 2 different Activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my MainActivity I have the following

```
      Intent myintent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayInformation.class);
            myintent.putExtra("displayName",userName.getText().toString());
            myintent.putExtra("displayContact",userContact.getText().toString());
            myintent.putExtra("displayAddress",userAddress.getText().toString());
            myintent.putExtra("displayStore",userStore.getSelectedItem().toString());
            myintent.putExtra("displayRequest",userRequest.getText().toString());
            startActivity(myintent);
```

I can display it correctly in my SecondActivity and here's the code

```
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        textView1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayName"));
        textView2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayContact"));
        textView3.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayAddress"));
        textView4.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayStore"));
        textView5.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayRequest"));
Intent myintent=new Intent(DisplayInformation.this, Confirmation.class);
                    myintent.putExtra("confirmID",smsCode.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(myintent);
```

Problem is when I use it in my ThirdActivity, it doesn't work.

```
TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmName);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmContact);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmAddress);
        TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmStore);
        TextView textView6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmRequest);

textView2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayName"));
        textView3.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayContact"));
        textView4.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayAddress"));
        textView5.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayStore"));
        textView6.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("displayRequest"));
```

There's no error or anything. Just that it doesn't show the value in ThirdActivity. Any idea how to go about ? I want to display the same info in ThirdActivity.

Comment: add the code where you are calling 2nd and 3rd activity

Comment: What do you want? DisplayContact, Address, Store, Request in third activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put all the data again in the intent before sending it to Third activity.

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(DisplayInformation.this, Confirmation.class);
                myintent.putExtra("confirmID", smsCode.getText().toString());
                myintent.putExtra("displayName", textView1.getText().toString());
                myintent.putExtra("displayContact", textView2.getText().toString());
                myintent.putExtra("displayAddress", textView3.getText().toString());
                myintent.putExtra("displayStore", textView4.getSelectedItem().toString());
                myintent.putExtra("displayRequest", textView5.getText().toString());
                startActivity(myintent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show anything because the second Intent doesn't contain the values your are trying to get. Actually, you are putting only the "confirmID" value in your second Intent. If you want also the other values you have to set them even in the second Intent, in the same way you have done with the first one.